# Python 3 - pd.to_datetime is not recognizing the timezone

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I have the following datetime column which is timezone aware to 'Pacific/Auckland':

```
startTime = ['2018-10-10 23:00:00+1300'
     , '2018-10-11 04:00:00+1300'
     , '2018-10-10 17:30:00+1300'
     , '2018-10-10 17:30:00+1300'
     , '2018-10-11 04:00:00+1300'
     , '2018-10-10 19:00:00+1300']
```

When I apply pd.to_datetime to the column the times are not being converted accordingly.

I am getting this:

```
pd.to_datetime(startTime)

DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-10 10:00:00'
             , '2018-10-10 15:00:00'
             , '2018-10-10 04:30:00'
             , '2018-10-10 04:30:00'
             , '2018-10-10 15:00:00'
             , '2018-10-10 06:00:00']
             , dtype='datetime64[ns]'
             , freq=None)
```

And I would expect the +13 hours to be added on not subtracted giving me to give localized times in Auckland NZ:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-11 12:00:00'
             , '2018-10-11 17:00:00'
             , ‘2018-10-11 06:30:00'
             , ‘2018-10-11 06:30:00'
             , ‘2018-10-11 17:00:00'
             , ‘2018-10-11 08:00:00']
             , dtype='datetime64[ns]'
             , freq=None)
```

Can someone please help me understand why pd.to_datetime is subtracting the 13 hours instead of adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been [previously raised](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16898) in the Pandas development and is tracked under [#13712](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13712).

For now, one workaround is to convert your timezone-aware strings to [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html), which correctly infers the timezone and then apply `pd.to_datetime`.

```
from pandas import Timestamp
converted = [Timestamp(t) for t in startTime]
pd.to_datetime(converted)
```

Which gives:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-10 23:00:00+13:00', '2018-10-11 04:00:00+13:00',
               '2018-10-10 17:30:00+13:00', '2018-10-10 17:30:00+13:00',
               '2018-10-11 04:00:00+13:00', '2018-10-10 19:00:00+13:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(780)]', freq=None)
```